# repeating the Encrypt function along the length of the bina function

Tags: c#

I want to repeat the Encrypt function along the entire length of the bina / how to do it?

```
private void carbonFiberButton11_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = PairConcat(Encrypt(), bina());
        }

    public static string PairConcat(string Encrypt, string bina)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for(; i<Encrypt.Length & i < bina.Length; i++)
        {
            result.Append(Encrypt[i].ToString());
            result.Append(bina[i].ToString());
        }
        result.Append(Encrypt.Substring(i));
        result.Append(bina.Substring(i));
        return result.ToString();

    }
```

For example:

```
string bina = "1234567";
string Encrypt = "abcdefg";
textbox1.text = 1a2b3c4d.. ;but it is doesn't works if I have different length:

string bina = "12345"
string Encrypt = "abc"
textbox1.text = 1a2b3c45 , but I need - 1a2b3c4a5b.
```

Encrypt function:

```
string Encrypt() //random to binary
        {
            var encrypt = textBox4.Text;

            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();           
            for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.Length; i++)
            {
                binary.Append(Convert.ToString(encrypt[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
            }
            return binary.ToString();

        }
```

I can't understand what to do/ Help me, please

Comment: What is `Encrypt()`?

Comment: it is a function for converting string to binary

Comment: I dont understand neither what your trying to do nor your description of the Encrypt function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `Encrypt` string in minimum as long as the `bina` string.

```
// Calculate smallest multiple of Encrypt.Length at least as long as bina.Length
int lb = bina.Length;
int le = Encrypt.Length;
int bufferLength = (lb + le - 1) / le * le;

var sb = new StringBuilder(Encrypt, bufferLength);
while (sb.Length < lb) {
    sb.Append(Encrypt);
}
Encrypt = sb.ToString();

string result = String.Join("", bina.Zip(Encrypt, (a, b) => a.ToString() + b));
```

The LINQ `Zip` method combines 2 sequences by providing pairs of items from the two sequences until one sequence ends. Here the sequences consist of chars.

The StringBuilder works most efficiently if does not have to resize its internal buffer. I calculate it by using integer arithmetic.

Comment: can I do it without LINQ?